# APA Cross-referencing Several Items from One Anthology

Tags: citations, academic-writing, research, apa

I am using a couple edited books in a paper I am writing. From each one, I need to cite 2-3 chapters.

MLA offers a way to "cross-reference" within a reference list when citing multiple chapters from the same anthology (see  https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/06/ about halfway down the page).

However, my paper is in APA format. Is there any such way to do this in APA references, or do I need the full citation for each chapter I am citing?

Answer (score 1):

In APA, if the whole book has been written by the same author(s), you always cite the whole book and give the page of the reference, thus:

> **Reference list:**
>   Author, A. A. (1967). *Title of Work*. Location: Publisher.
>   
>   **In text:**
>   ... (Author, 1967, p. xxx) ...

If you cite a text in an anthology or a chapter in a textbook where every chapter has been written by a different author, you cite it like this:

> **Reference list:**
>   Author, A. A., & Author, B. B. (1958). Title of text. In A. Editor & B. Editor (eds.), *Title of Book* (pp. xxx-xxx). Location: Publisher.
>   
>   **In text:**
>   ... (Author & Author, 1958, p. xxx) ...

In APA you need to create a citation for every individual text. There is no "cross-referencing" of the kind allowed by MLA. You can cite the whole anthology, if the individual texts all endorse a common viewpoint and you are refering to this (e.g. a collection of texts about a new theory or methodology).

Refer to the APA Manual for more information. You find it in every university or large public library.

Comment: On the phrasing "chapters from an anthology," my mistake; I was mixing phrasing from the Purdue OWL **MLA** section, which refers to an "A Work in an _Anthology,_ Reference, or Collection," which "may include an essay in an edited collection or anthology, or a _chapter_ of a book," (see same link cited above) and the **APA** section, which denotes this as "Article or _Chapter_ in an _Edited Book_" (see [link](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/08/)) (emphases mine). That is what I mean. Regarding what I mean by "cross-referencing," did you read the original link? Thanks.